# Python datetime list

Tags: python, list, date, datetime

I have a list of datetime objects:

```
t = [datetime.date(2014, 12, 30), datetime.date(2015, 1, 2), datetime.date(2015, 1, 3), datetime.date(2015, 1, 5), datetime.date(2015, 2, 19)]
```

When returning the first item of the list `t[0]` the result is `2014-12-30`. Is there any way I can get the result to be `datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)` instead?

Comment: It *is* a `datetime.time` object, you're just seeing the `__str__` rather than the `__repr__`.

Comment: `print t[0]` may seem like `2014-12-30` but `type(t[0])` is `datetime.date`

Comment: I don't know what version of python you're using because when you access the elements of the above you will get a date object and not a date string which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`t[0]` **is** a `datetime.date` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = [datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)]
>>> t
[datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)]
>>> type(t[0])
<type 'datetime.date'>
>>> t[0]
datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)
```

If you `print` it, you will see the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) (*"string"*) version of the object:

```
>>> print t[0]
2014-12-30
```

If you want to see the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (*"representation"*), be explicit:

```
>>> print repr(t[0])
datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)
```

or, if you're using it as part of a larger string:

```
>>> '{!r}'.format(t[0])
'datetime.date(2014, 12, 30)'
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems what you doing is printing the result of t[0].
so given this piece of example:

```
In [20]: d1 = datetime.date.today()

In [21]: d2 = datetime.date.today()

In [22]: l = [d1, d2]

In [23]: l
Out[23]: [datetime.date(2015, 4, 7), datetime.date(2015, 4, 7)]

In [23]: l
Out[23]: [datetime.date(2015, 4, 7), datetime.date(2015, 4, 7)]

In [24]: l[0]
Out[24]: datetime.date(2015, 4, 7)

In [25]: print l[0]
2015-04-07

In [26]: print type(l[0])
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

You are getting type of 'datetime.date' and datetime.date(2015, 4, 7) as a return from slicing the list. But this class string representation is defaulted to %Y-%m-%d which **prints** 2015-04-07

If you'll provide more code and explain what you trying to achieve I will be able to update the answer.